# ng-bind-html is removing the paragraph spaces

Tags: css, angularjs

I can bind text to my screen using ng-bind-html. This works fine until a paragraph break is added, somehow the spacing gets removed. So for instance, if i am pulling the data from database and there are paragraph breaks, all of the text appear as one big chunk. Is there a way to fix this with css or something? No idea what is causing this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-bind-html="selectedItem|unsafe" style="color:red" class="ng-binding">hi worlds: i am malory</div>
```

Comment: Please show us the raw text whose paragraph breaks are being removed.

Comment: But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.

Comment: if this chunk of text is pulled from the database, it will not add paragraph breaks. It will be one big chunk instead of spaced out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if I understand correctly, but you have ng-bind-html on a div, not a paragraph tag. So, if you want the data pulled in as a paragraph (default browser styling/spacing for a paragraph) you'd change the div tags to p tags?